# Angular Reactive forms : how to reset form state and keep values after submit

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-reactive-forms

In an Angular reactive form. How to reset only the **state** of form after successful submit?

Here is the process:

- Create the form and `setValue` from service result
- Modify values and submit the form
- If form is properly submitted to service, then reset and keep values

**How to keep values as modified and reset the form to its pristine state.**

A form.reset() simply empty the form. But if I don't call it, the state is not reset and for example my validations depending on form state classes (pristine, dirty, valid etc.) are still there.

Comment: I usually create a method like initForm, which i call on ngInit, and again after submitting the form

Answer (score 107, accepted):

The solution of @smnbbrv works pretty well.

You can also provide your actual form value to reset() method.

Given the fact `myReactiveForm` is a Reactive form in your component. After successful submit of your form (by calling a service for example), then your can do:

```js
this.myReactiveForm.reset(this.myReactiveForm.value);
```

It will reset the form and set the "new" form values to the same value you form had.

This method can be see within Tour of Hero example [Official Angular.io doc](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/reactive-forms.html#!#_reset_-the-form-flags)

Comment: This is so much a hack :D However, I must admit it should work ;)

Comment: Yep! We can find amazing solutions by reading Angular doc. These guys are so... brilliant!

Comment: Well I'm tired to read it after reading it four times since angular2 beta, so I will leave it to the ones who likes it :) I actually don't find this to be a good solution, because it unnecessarily rewrites all the form values and it might cause performance problems on huge forms.

Comment: Tried and this solution does not work. 


Because reactive form receives latest value from input fields right away, the "this.myReactiveForm.value" passed to the "reset" method does not reflect the prior state of the form, rather it is the latest value on the form. Thus this way of reset results in a no-op.  


The form under this solution stays unchanged instead of being reverted/reset to a prior state as expected.

Answer (score 40):

That's pretty much easy:

```
this.form.markAsPristine();
this.form.markAsUntouched();
```

This resets the form metadata and the form is pristine again

Comment: Is this removes validation part also?

Comment: @sireeshaj depends exactly what you mean. See my answer if you're using angular material controls.

Answer (score 31):

#### Caution for users of @angular/components (material)

There's an added complication if you're using angular material controls, with `mat-error` to display your errors. Such errors are displayed based on the result of an `ErrorStateMatcher` (in addition to any `*ngIf` you may have applied).

The [default ErrorStateMatcher](https://github.com/angular/material2/blob/master/src/lib/core/error/error-options.ts) displays errors based on a boolean:

```
isErrorState(control: FormControl | null, form: FormGroupDirective | NgForm | null): boolean 
{
   return !!(control && control.invalid && (control.touched || (form && form.submitted)));
}
```

So what this means in English is:

> If the form has *ever* been submitted and one if its controls becomes invalid
> (per validation rules) then the error will be displayed.

This is often not what you want (especially if you're reading this question!).

Looking at the source code - there isn't a way to set `submitted = false` unless you call [`resetForm`](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/packages/forms/src/directives/ng_form.ts) on the ngForm directive (not the FormGroup object). Setting states as pristine or untouched don't reset submitted to false.

If you're using `mat-error` you may find it easier to create your own ErrorStateMatcher (simple interface) for custom logic if this is an issue.

Note: ErrorStateMatcher is only in angular material - and not a part of standard angular forms.

Comment: tldr: get a template variable from the ngForm directive and pass it to your reset method. Then call `resetForm` on it.

Comment: As this answer points out, when in this situation (where validators will show errors on the form when restting the form with `FormGroup#reset()`, use a template variable ```<form #login="ngForm" ... >``` and either pass login template variable to your `(ngSubmit)="submit(login)"` function and call `resetForm() ` on it. OR to not have to rely on the submit event, use `@ViewChild('login') private _loginNgForm: NgForm;` and then `this._loginNgForm.resetForm();`

Answer (score 15):

**04-06-2020:** Ionic 5+ and Angular 9+

Just a single line. i.e. `this.form.reset();`

> Resets the FormGroup, marks all descendants are marked pristine and untouched, and the value of all descendants to null.

```
 form: FormGroup;

 constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder, ) { }

  resetTheForm(): void {
    this.form.reset();
  }
```

Answer (score 5):

**For reactive forms what worked for me when using angular 7**: was to use template-driven form and pass it via the form submit handler like so

```
// component.html
 <form #f="ngForm" [formGroup]="form" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(f)" novalidate>
 ....
</form>


// component.ts

onSubmit(form: NgForm) {

// reset form here
 form.form.markAsPristine();
 form.resetForm();
}
```

It will reset the form and the submitted state to default.

Answer (score 5):

I used the **patch value** to clear the reactive form controls. it worked for me. please try the below code.

```
onClear() {
   this.formGroup.patchValue({
     fieldName: ''
   });
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Adding a another answers, if you have a disabled input in your form, use **getRawValue()** as a parameter of **ngForm.resetForm()**. See the sample:

in HTML:

```
<form
  (ngSubmit)="formSubmit(myForm)"
  #myForm="ngForm"
>
    ...
</form>
```

in .TS:

```
formSubmit(myForm: NgForm) {
   myForm.resetForm(myForm.form.getRawValue());
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Some time `this.myForm.reset(this.myForm.value);` may not reset to initial values
So it is better to create a separate function to initialize the form and call it in ngOnInit() and before call `this.myForm.reset(this.myForm.value);`

```
ngOnInit(){
  myFormValues();
}

myFormValues() {
  this.myForm= this.fb.group({
      id: ['', Validators.required],
      name: ['', Validators.required],
    });
}

submitForm() {
  // save data
  myFormValues();
  this.myForm.reset(this.myForm.value)
}
```