# Handling mandatory fields with form clear - Angular

Tags: angular, typescript

Form containing a bunch of required fields are there. Here I am able to handle all validations and error messages perfectly. But when I clear the form, now error messaging displaying for mandatory filed's like "Field is mandatory". 
Here my expected behavior is when clear the form just form comes to the initial stage and not to validate any field.

I'm not getting any idea to handle this, So any idea or any suggestion is helpful for me. Thanks in advance.

At present, I am using Reactive forms and through a generic validator to handle validations like below.

Comment: can you share your code

Comment: What type of form are you using ? If reactive form then while showing validation feedback .. use <formcontrol>.touched && <formcontrol>.errors. in *ngIf as a condition.

Comment: @Chellappan updated

Comment: @ShubhamYerawar Yes using Reactive forms and updated validation code as well.

Comment: This is something new for me .. can you put up a minimal code which I can replicate to get your issue .

Comment: @Royal please share your reset method also

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to show error messages when:

(1) there is an error on a field AND

(2) the field is dirty or touched - in other words, when the field has not been tampered with. Initially a field is not dirty and not touched. When you change the value it becomes dirty. When you give the field focus and then it loses focus it is touched. I believe resetting the form like you describe should make all fields clean again and untouched.

Manage dirty and touched like this:

```
<label>
  First Name:
  <input formControlName="firstName" required> <!-- required is optional -->
</label>

<div *ngIf="firstName.invalid && (firstName.dirty || firstName.touched)" class="alert alert-danger">
  <div *ngIf="firstName.errors.required">Name required</div>
  <div *ngIf="firstName.errors.minlength">Name min length is 3</div>
</div>
```

Docs: https://angular.io/guide/form-validation

Comment: Thank you soo much for your answer, Now I'm able do all validation's perfectly but problem with clearing the form. As you suggested how to make all fields clean when clear the form.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43759590/angular-reactive-forms-how-to-reset-form-state-and-keep-values-after-submit

Comment: this.myForm.resetForm();

Comment: If that doesn't work try this ... https://malcoded.com/posts/angular-fundamentals-reactive-forms#b16b1dab-5cba-4272-ad36-ada3346bb2ae ... which just uses this.myForm.reset(); ... this should not only clear the values (or you can provide values to reset) but should also reset the touched and dirty flags

Comment: Thank you, yes we can reset by using this.formname.reset()